# How should I access a module internal variable across typescript module fragments?

Tags: module, typescript, internal

I have a typescript module that is split across two files,
and tsc (version 0.9.1.1) compiled it without errors, and the produced code ran correctly.

Here is a summary of the source file for my module:
**split_module_example.ts**:

```
//file: orders.part1.ts
module Orders {  // first part of Orders
    export var msg : string;
    // set orders here
    msg = 'hello';
}

//file: orders.part1.ts
module Orders {  // second part of Orders
    export var msg : string;
    // reference orders here
    console.log('orders=' + msg);
}
```

the compiler generates this javascript, which looks correct to me:

```
//file: orders.part1.ts
var Orders;
(function (Orders) {
    Orders.msg;
    Orders.msg = 'hello';
})(Orders || (Orders = {}));

//file: orders.part1.ts
var Orders;
(function (Orders) {
    Orders.msg;

    // reference orders here
    console.log('orders=' + Orders.msg);
})(Orders || (Orders = {}));
```

I just upgraded my TypeScript compiler from 0.9.1.1 to 0.9.5.0.

But now when I run tsc:

```
tsc --out split_module_example.js split_module_example.ts
```

it issues this error:

```
split_module_example.ts(9,16): error TS2000: Duplicate identifier 'msg'.
```

However, the code still runs correctly.

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong, or if there was a bug introduced in the 0.9.5.0 compiler.

- If I'm doing something wrong, what is the correct way to reference a module internal variable across module fragments?
- If the compiler is wrong, is there a workaround?

Comment: BTW, you can see this behavior by pasting the split_module_example.ts file from above into the [TypeScript Play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/) site. Then open the debugger feature of your browser so you can see the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have the variable declared in exactly one location. Just remove the `var` declaration from all but one of the modules and everything will work as expected.

Comment: However, if I remove the **export** keyword, it stops working. Is there a way to share this variable so it is private to the module?

Comment: No. (comments must be at least 15 characters in length)

Comment: Again, thanks so much. I've become a big fan of TypeScript. Kudos to you and your team for making javascript work!